# Синонимизировать метку [error404] с [http-status-code-404]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метку [error404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error404) с [http-status-code-404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404). (Есть ещё [error-404](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-404), но она уже синонимизирована).

Comment: На enSO есть ещё [`404-page`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/404-page), которая не связана с остальными. Интересно, это недосмотр или всё же надо разделять.